# Mobx store function call in another Observer component

Tags: react-native, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-state-tree

I have a Mobx Store and i am passing this store inside the Provider and when i am consoling **this.props** its showing the structure of Mobx store.

Below is my Mobx Store

```
import { observable, computed, action, useStrict, runInAction, toJS } from 'mobx';

// useStrict(true);

class OpenPropertiesStore {

  @observable openProperties = {};

  @action
  fetchOpenProperties() {
    fetch(`http://uinames.com/api/`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        runInAction(() => {
          this.openProperties = data;
          this.name = "abhinav";
        })
      })
  }

  @computed get getOpenProperties() {
    return this.openProperties;
  }

}

export default new OpenPropertiesStore();
```

Inside Component i am calling ComponentDidMount
where if i am printing "this.props" it showing the store.
But i cannnot call the function like this

```
@inject('UserStore', 'CityStore', 'OpenPropertiesStore')
@observer
export default class Navigation extends Component {
   componentDidMount = async () => {
      const { CityStore, UserStore, OpenPropertiesStore } = this.props;
      const data = OpenPropertiesStore.getOpenProperties();
   }
}
```

giving me the error

> YellowBox.js:67 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
>   TypeError: OpenPropertiesStore.getOpenProperties is not a function
>   TypeError: OpenPropertiesStore.getOpenProperties is not a function

anyone know how to solve this error

Comment: You have a mistake in your code. Instead of doing a job in `componentDidMount` method - you are redefining it for this particular component. `componentDidMount = async () => ` - you overwrite method. But need to `componentDidMount(){ your code here}`

Answer (score 0):

MobX computed should not be called as a function, access them like a property.

```
const data = OpenPropertiesStore.getOpenProperties;
```

Also if you just want to return a property from store - no need to write a separate @computed for it, as you do not do any computation in it. Just access it directly

```
const data = OpenPropertiesStore.openProperties;
```